# SQLite - Retrieve BLOB Encrypted Data

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve blob encrypted data from a sqlite file. Here is my current code:

```
sqlite3 *db; char *error;
int rc;
rc = sqlite3_open("db.sq", &db);
if (rc)
{
    cout << "Connection Error";
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
else {
    char **results = NULL;
    int rows, columns;
    const char *sqlSelect = "SELECT password FROM users";
    sqlite3_get_table(db, sqlSelect, &results, &rows, &columns, &error);
    if (rc) {
        system("color 0c");
        cout << "Query Error";
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 2; i < rows*2; i += 1) {
            cout << results[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing this prints, however, is a bunch of smiley faces. I assume that I am getting the data wrong, as I remember seeing a way to get blob information in the documentation, but I am not sure how to implement that.

The documentation for blob: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html

Comment: You check `rc` after `sqlite3_get_table` call - but you aren't actually assigning the return value of the call to `rc`. Also, why do you expect there to be `rows*2` entries in the table, and why do you expect the data to start with index 2 (as opposed to `rows` and `1`)?

Comment: Finally, you apparently retrieve binary data - what do you expect it to look like when printed, if not a bunch of seemingly random garbage?